# No Boot Device Available - In setup BIOS tab unable to arrow up/down to change boot sequence

Tags: boot, keyboard-shortcuts, bios

Dell Desktop Inspiron 3646, TAG ID 5QKB822, Windows 10.
Original problem started with an update that went into an endless loop; tried automatic repair and at 68% it also restarted an endless loop, at this point I tried to get into Save Mode, following several suggested ways from the Internet to no avail.  HD Dianostic tested fine. Tried function keys: F1 [repeated error above] F2 [Worked], F5/F6 [same as F1], F8 and Shift F8 [same as F1], F9, F10 & F11 [same as F1] and F12 [Worked].
Once in Setup Utility, I could arrow across the tabs but not arrow up/down within the sub-items, especially in the BIOS tab to use the USB boot setting. It wasn't over, for next the Black SOD showed up without a cursor, and finally I have the error as stated above.
First, how do I get those up/down arrow keys to work?
Secondly, Other suggestions to fix this problem will be greatly appreciated
FLJerry

Answer (score 0):

Since the Windows OS on the disk has been so badly damaged as to make the PC unbootable, but you can access BIOS:

1. Make bootable USB [Windows 10 installation media](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10) on another Windows PC using a flash USB drive of at least 8 GB (but very much larger is a disadvantage, as it might not be a bootable file system).
2. [Reinstall Windows](https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6734-windows-10-installation-tool.html) from ISO, keeping files. **N.B.** It is a *very* good idea to make a full disk image *first*.